# How can I use the REDCap calculation function to get a specific result?

Tags: syntax, calculation, redcap

I want to build a calculation that returns 1 if var1 is at least 2 AND var2 is at least 1, else return 0.

I think I have to use an if then else statement but I continue to get syntax errors.

This is what I have tried so far:

`if [var1] >=2 AND [var2] >= 1, 1,0`

this has not been successful so far.

Comment: I tried ```if([var1]>1 and [var2]>1, 1, 0)``` and that worked

Comment: Glad you worked it out. The syntax of the if() function (and everything else) is documented in several places in REDCap. Try the built-in Help&FAQs, or the help text in a calculated field.